# .html() taking more time to load data on screen in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination, sofea

i am facing performance issue (i.e  it is taking more time to load data on screen ) in  IE11 .where as in  FF its loading quickly . we are using  sofea framework and i have found that pagination functionality is taking more time to execute,)

we are using below to append the data to tbody

```
$('tbody[data-page=' + page + ']', this._table).html(newPages[i].rows);
```

we tried below using innerHTML

```
var element = $('tbody[data-page=' + page + ']', this._table);
element.innerHTML = newPages[i].rows;
```

in debug data is  assigning to element.innerHTML but it is not displaying on the screen.

any alternative solution to improve loading performance

Comment: That's because `element` isn't a DOM node, it's a jQuery object. You could try `var element = $('tbody[data-page=' + page + ']', this._table).get(0);` to get at the underlying node, but I'm not sure that will fix your performance issue.

Comment: you mean to say that                                                                                   
var element = $('tbody[data-page=' + page +']',this._table).get(newPages[i].rows); like this i need to try

Comment: No. That's not what I mean. [This is what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/uuh594u4/).

Comment: for(var i=0, iLen=newPages.length; i < iLen; i++){
            var page = newPages[i].pageNum;
            console.log("rowsappendstrt", new Date());
            this._table.append(paginatorTpl.NewTableBody({page: page}));
            $('tbody[data-page=' + page + ']', this._table).html(newPages[i].rows);
            console.log("rowsappendend", new Date());
        }             
actually we are using this for loop . if i use get(0). i wont be able to append all the dynamic data

Comment: any alternative solution

Comment: can you please suggest on this